# How to pass a deduced function pointer type to a function pointer template argument

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to instantiate `Caller<pfn>` from the constructor `Foo()`?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    template<void(*pfn)()>
    struct Caller
    {
        static void call() { pfn(); }
    };

    template<typename FN>
    Foo(FN fn)
    {
        Caller<FN>::call();  // illegal type for non-type template parameter 'pfn'
    }
};

void Bar()
{
    cout << "bar" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo foo(&Bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, not from this constructor. Function parameters are not (assumed to be) compile-time constants. What do you want to achieve? Maybe it's possible in another way.

Comment: Why `Caller` needs to be a template? You can pass `pfn` to it through a constructor.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid storing a copy of pfn inside Caller, but while retrieving the function pointer from the constructor Foo() by deduction. My real code needs several function pointers, so storage goes up, and syntax gets messy. Thought there may be some trick I can use here.

Comment: also, I am passing member functions, which would require another template parameter, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: "but while retrieving the function pointer from the constructor Foo() by deduction" Use `auto`? E.g. `auto foo = &Bar;` or wrap the function pointer in some class (as a non-type template parameter, see sehe's solution) and then use a function to deduce it, e.g. `auto foo = make_fptr_type(&Bar);`

Comment: I don't know if I have explained this right. I get the fptr's  type through deduction, along with a non-compile-time-constant fptr, and I need to somehow instantiate a template that takes a function pointer. This is probably not possible.

Comment: So you want to invoke a function, but *not* via a pointer or reference to it? I.e. you want to do it just by deduction of its *type*, then somehow have that type magically resolve to an instance of said-same (which would be the function pointer, but thats somewhat the point of all this avoidance) ? In case it wasn't obvious, your question is not entirely "clear".

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the function's type for class not just for constructor. It's just a workaround and you can use it as a start point:

```
template <typename F>
struct Foo
{
    struct Caller
    {
        static void call(F fn)
        {
            fn();
        }
    };

    Foo(F fn)
    {
        Caller::call(fn);
    }
};

void Bar()
{
    cout << "bar" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo<decltype(Bar)> foo(Bar);
}
```

---

If `Foo` can not be template base then use this:

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename F>
    struct Caller
    {
        static void call(F fn)
        {
            fn();
        }
    };

    template <typename F>
    Foo(F fn)
    {
        Caller<F>::call(fn);
    }
};

void Bar()
{
    cout << "bar" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo(Bar);
}
```

Comment: for my needs, Foo cannot be a template

Comment: in my real use case, Caller needs to be called later on, and must contain several function pointers. If they were passed as template parameters, I could avoid the storage cost, but I am trying to do that without explicitly passing them through template args, because they are member functions, and they are many, so it would be messy

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant something like he following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    template<void(*pfn)()> // CHANGED
    struct Caller
    {
        static void call() { pfn(); }
    };
};

void Bar()
{
    cout << "bar" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Foo::Caller<&Bar>::call(); // CHANGED
}
```

note the change here:

```
 template<void(*pfn)()>
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid passing the function pointer explicitly as a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

A compile time constant function pointer cannot be used as one after being passed as a function argument.

Also, a compile time constant function pointer for a specific a function cannot be obtained using a function pointer type alone.